# invalid file name in asset folder

Tags: android

Error generating final archive: java.io.FileNotFoundException:C:\Users\Webrich\AndroidWorkspace\Android UK Signs\bin\resources.ap_ does not exist   Android UK Signs Unknown    Android Packaging Problem
how to fix this error A modern version of the traditional fingerpost may be used at some junctions on minor rural roads.png invalid filename in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: You shouldn't store the png file in res/assets but in res/drawable

Is

```
A modern version of the traditional fingerpost may be used at some junctions on minor rural roads.png
```

a file?

Try shortening its name and avoid blank spaces.

Comment: yes image file but it was accepted remaining file except this image file

Comment: maybe this name is larger than the rest. Did you shorten it? Anyway, try cleaning and building the project again.

Comment: You shouldn't store the png file in res/assets but in res/drawable. Are you aware of that? Store the file name in res/values/strings.xml and use it as title.